# Please let me know how to fix this issue? PolicyError: not authorized `out/cancer_1/simOutput/growthCurve.pdf' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/412

Tags: python, imagemagick, google-colaboratory

[Using it in colab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHIqk.png)

I tried to fix this issue by using following command but still not helpful

```
from pathlib import Path

policy_path = Path("/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml")
orig_policy = policy_path.read_text()
new_policy = orig_policy.replace('', '')
policy_path.write_text(new_policy)
```

Comment: Apparently no permission to write to the Imagemagick policy.xml. See https://imagemagick.org/script/security-policy.php

Comment: If the `policy.xml` isn't correct, you fix it once for all with an editor using an id that has admin rights. Doing it in your code (why do so anyway because once it's done it should stay that way) would require your code to run with admin privileges, which is a definite no-no these days.

Comment: The error message you give doesn't match the code. ImageMagick by default restricts reading PDFs. Perhaps convert the PDF first to an image.

Answer (score 0):

Install `poppler-utils` in colab with:

```
!sudo apt install poppler-utils
```

Use it to extract the images with:

```
!pdfimages rose.pdf x
!ls
```

and then you can read the images (by default ppm) with imagemagick.